# write.table with a specific day of the week derived from sys.date

Tags: r, date

I want to save a file name for the Tuesday of every week regardless of when the script was run. For example, it does not matter whether I run the script on Monday or Friday, I want the file name to be saved as the date of the Tuesday of that week. Is there a way of doing this?

```
today = format(Sys.Date(), '%Y%m%d')
write.table(data, glue("{my_folder_path}/output/weather_files_{today}.csv"),
            na = "",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = TRUE,
            append = FALSE,
            sep = ",")
```

Comment: When do you change to the next Tuesday? Like if you run on Sunday, does it go to the previous Tuesday or the next Tuesday?

Comment: It always goes to the Tuesday of that specific week. So if it's a Monday, it will be the Tuesday after. If it's a Wednesday, Thursday or Friday, it's the Tuesday before.

Comment: So what happens on Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: Oh! I doubt that would ever be the case but it would also be the Tuesday before. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

`cut.Date` will give Monday so add 1.

```
today <- Sys.Date(); today
## [1] "2024-02-01"

as.Date(cut(today, "week")) + 1
## [1] "2024-01-30"
```

Comment: I would have expected `trunc.Date` to support weeks (it doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

The `wday` function from `lubridate` tells you the weekday of any given date by returning a numeric value of 1-7 representing Sunday through Saturday. That means that Tuesday gets a 3. We can therefore find the number of days between today's date and the Tuesday of the current week by doing:

```r
(3 - lubridate::wday(Sys.Date()))
#> [1] -2
```

Which means Tuesday was two days ago (correct at the time of writing). Since we can add or subtract integers to dates to represent adding or subtracting days, we can simply do:

```r
Sys.Date() + (3 - wday(Sys.Date()))
#> [1] "2024-01-30"
```

This gives us the date of the Tuesday of the current week. You can format it however you like, for example:

```r
format(Sys.Date() + (3 - wday(Sys.Date())), '%Y%m%d')
#> [1] "20240130"
```

Answer (score 3):

Some magic:

```
format(
 as.Date(
  as.POSIXlt((Sys.time() + 86400 * (2 - as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$wday)))), 
'%Y%m%d')
```

`as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$wday` return a numerical weekday (range 0-6, Sunday = 0). 2 is Tuesday. Subtracting both you get the number of days that you need to add or subtract from current time. 86400 is the number of seconds in a day.

EDIT: Can be simplified to

```
dd <- Sys.Date()
format(dd + (2 - as.POSIXlt(dd)$wday), '%Y%m%d')
```

It also suppress an unlikely race condition (midnight calls, one just before, one just after) while calling two times the current date/time.

Comment: Welcome to the party, Alenvers! I keep forgetting about `as.POSIXlt`, it's so not usable (compared to `POSIXct`) in most of my work, but the embedded values within its structure can be quite useful for things like this. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

A longer-path to get there is below (the other answers took much less time to type :-).

The hint can be found in the `%`-code of `?strptime`, where `%u` (1-based, Monday=1) and `%w` (0-based, Sunday=0) indicates the weekday.

```r
dates <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2024-02-01") + 0:13) |>
  transform(
    `%u` = format(date, format="%u"),
    `%w` = format(date, format="%w"),
    check.names=FALSE)
dates
#          date %u %w
# 1  2024-02-01  4  4
# 2  2024-02-02  5  5
# 3  2024-02-03  6  6
# 4  2024-02-04  7  0
# 5  2024-02-05  1  1
# 6  2024-02-06  2  2
# 7  2024-02-07  3  3
# 8  2024-02-08  4  4
# 9  2024-02-09  5  5
# 10 2024-02-10  6  6
# 11 2024-02-11  7  0
# 12 2024-02-12  1  1
# 13 2024-02-13  2  2
# 14 2024-02-14  3  3
```

where `2024-02-1` is a Thursday. This means we are interested in when *either* of those formats is equal to `2`, Tuesday in both.

```r
dates |>
  transform(
    tuesday = date - (as.integer(format(dates$date, format = "%w")) + 3) %% 7 - 2, 
    check.names = FALSE)
#          date %u %w    tuesday
# 1  2024-02-01  4  4 2024-01-30
# 2  2024-02-02  5  5 2024-01-30
# 3  2024-02-03  6  6 2024-01-30
# 4  2024-02-04  7  0 2024-01-30
# 5  2024-02-05  1  1 2024-01-30
# 6  2024-02-06  2  2 2024-01-30
# 7  2024-02-07  3  3 2024-01-30
# 8  2024-02-08  4  4 2024-02-06
# 9  2024-02-09  5  5 2024-02-06
# 10 2024-02-10  6  6 2024-02-06
# 11 2024-02-11  7  0 2024-02-06
# 12 2024-02-12  1  1 2024-02-06
# 13 2024-02-13  2  2 2024-02-06
# 14 2024-02-14  3  3 2024-02-06
```

The `-2` is to look for Tuesdays, the rest of the `+3)%%7` is to find the nearest Tuesday ... you might also prefer an `ifelse` or `case_when` solution that allows a different pivot (e.g., Sat/Sun).

So, long-story-short,

```r
Sys.Date() + (as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), format="%w"))+3) %% 7 - 2
# [1] "2024-01-30"
```

---

Inspired by @G.Grothendieck's mention of `cut.Date`, I wonder why `trunc` does not support `units="week"`. Here's one such hack. (And I'll use @Alenvers' use of `POSIXlt`.)

```r
#' @param date 'Date' object or something that can be converted to it
#' @param wday 'integer', week day to truncate/round to, Sunday is 0
#' @return the Date for the preceding day-of-week indicate
trunc_week <- function(date, wday = 0) {
  if (!inherits(date, "Date")) date <- as.Date(date)
  date - (as.POSIXlt(date)$wday - wday) %% 7
}
round_week <- function(date, wday = 0) {
  if (!inherits(date, "Date")) date <- as.Date(date)
  date - as.POSIXlt(date)$wday + wday
}

dates |>
  transform(
    trunc_sun = trunc_week(date),
    trunc_tues = trunc_week(date, 2),
    round_sun = round_week(date),
    round_tues = round_week(date, 2),
    check.names = FALSE)
#          date %u %w  trunc_sun trunc_tues  round_sun round_tues
# 1  2024-02-01  4  4 2024-01-28 2024-01-30 2024-01-28 2024-01-30
# 2  2024-02-02  5  5 2024-01-28 2024-01-30 2024-01-28 2024-01-30
# 3  2024-02-03  6  6 2024-01-28 2024-01-30 2024-01-28 2024-01-30
# 4  2024-02-04  7  0 2024-02-04 2024-01-30 2024-02-04 2024-02-06
# 5  2024-02-05  1  1 2024-02-04 2024-01-30 2024-02-04 2024-02-06
# 6  2024-02-06  2  2 2024-02-04 2024-02-06 2024-02-04 2024-02-06
# 7  2024-02-07  3  3 2024-02-04 2024-02-06 2024-02-04 2024-02-06
# 8  2024-02-08  4  4 2024-02-04 2024-02-06 2024-02-04 2024-02-06
# 9  2024-02-09  5  5 2024-02-04 2024-02-06 2024-02-04 2024-02-06
# 10 2024-02-10  6  6 2024-02-04 2024-02-06 2024-02-04 2024-02-06
# 11 2024-02-11  7  0 2024-02-11 2024-02-06 2024-02-11 2024-02-13
# 12 2024-02-12  1  1 2024-02-11 2024-02-06 2024-02-11 2024-02-13
# 13 2024-02-13  2  2 2024-02-11 2024-02-13 2024-02-11 2024-02-13
# 14 2024-02-14  3  3 2024-02-11 2024-02-13 2024-02-11 2024-02-13
```

Comment: Nice to see a base R solution. I've just realised that `as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$wday` will give the same output as `lubridate::wday`, so `Sys.Date() + (2 - as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$wday)` would be another simple base R method.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron ... I just added two base functions that satisfy my itch for `round(date, units="week")`